# C++ libcurl console progress bar

Tags: c++, console, progress-bar, libcurl

I would like a progress bar to appear in the console window while a file is being downloaded. My code is this: [Download file using libcurl in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636333/download-file-using-libcurl-in-c-c/1636827#1636827).

How to have a progress bar in libcurl?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your meter.

```
#include <math.h>

int progress_func(void* ptr, double TotalToDownload, double NowDownloaded, 
                    double TotalToUpload, double NowUploaded)
{
    // ensure that the file to be downloaded is not empty
    // because that would cause a division by zero error later on
    if (TotalToDownload <= 0.0)) {
        return 0;
    }

    // how wide you want the progress meter to be
    int totaldotz=40;
    double fractiondownloaded = NowDownloaded / TotalToDownload;
    // part of the progressmeter that's already "full"
    int dotz = (int) round(fractiondownloaded * totaldotz);

    // create the "meter"
    int ii=0;
    printf("%3.0f%% [",fractiondownloaded*100);
    // part  that's full already
    for ( ; ii < dotz;ii++) {
        printf("=");
    }
    // remaining part (spaces)
    for ( ; ii < totaldotz;ii++) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    // and back to line begin - do not forget the fflush to avoid output buffering problems!
    printf("]\r");
    fflush(stdout);
    // if you don't return 0, the transfer will be aborted - see the documentation
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just needed to include math.h and it works fine.

Comment: @fvu Hi Here i implemented way which you suggested but i didnt get any value in this function progress_func .

Comment: Beautiful i have adapted this to C works very very very well!

Comment: @workdreamer Glad you liked it, but I'm a bit puzzled, the code above *is* C ;)

Comment: @workdreamer thanks for the edit!  If you are using php, also check out [phpclimate](http://climate.thephpleague.com/terminal-objects/progress-bar/) for a simple way to make an even fancier bar :)

Comment: The lib is interesting. maybe i will use it later. now i am using your code :)

Answer (score 15):

From the [curl documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html)

> CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION
>
> Function pointer that should match the
>   curl_progress_callback prototype found
>   in . This function gets
>   called by libcurl instead of its
>   internal equivalent with a frequent
>   interval during operation (roughly
>   once per second) no matter if data is
>   being transfered or not.
>   Unknown/unused argument values passed
>   to the callback will be set to zero
>   (like if you only download data, the
>   upload size will remain 0). Returning
>   a non-zero value from this callback
>   will cause libcurl to abort the
>   transfer and return
>   CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK.

So:

You provide a function that looks like this

```
int progress_func(void* ptr, double TotalToDownload, double NowDownloaded, double TotalToUpload, double NowUploaded)
{
    // It's here you will write the code for the progress message or bar
}
```

And some extra options after the existing options

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);  // already there
// Internal CURL progressmeter must be disabled if we provide our own callback
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, FALSE);
// Install the callback function
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progress_func);
```

That's all that needs to be done

Comment: My problem is that I cannot make a working code for the progress bar.

Comment: @marios if i `put curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);`
// Install the callback function
`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progress_func);` then i get failed in download

Comment: @user1089679 make sure you're returning 0 in your callback

Answer (score 2):

Like apt progress bar

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <include/curl/curl.h>//Or #include <curl/curl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int nb_bar;
double last_progress, progress_bar_adv;

HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

int progress_bar (void *bar, double t, double d)
{
    if(last_progress != round(d/t*100))
    {
      nb_bar = 25;
      progress_bar_adv = round(d/t*nb_bar);

      cout<<"\r ";
      SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 160);
      cout<<" Progress : [ ";

      if(round(d/t*100) < 10)
      { cout<<"0"<<round(d/t*100)<<" %]"; }
      else
      { cout<<round(d/t*100)<<" %] "; }

      SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 15);
      cout<<" [";
      SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 10);
      for(int i = 0 ; i <= progress_bar_adv ; i++)
      { cout<<"#"; }
      SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 15);
      for(int i = 0 ; i < nb_bar - progress_bar_adv; i++)
      { cout<<"."; }

      cout<<"]";
      last_progress = round(d/t*100);
    }
  return 0;
}


int main()
{
  CURL *curl_download;
  FILE *fp;
  CURLcode res;
  string url = "http://www.gecif.net/articles/mathematiques/pi/pi_1_million.txt", output_file = "pi.txt";

  curl_download = curl_easy_init();

  if (curl_download)
  {
      //SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 11);
      fp = fopen(output_file.c_str(),"wb");

      curl_easy_setopt(curl_download, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
      curl_easy_setopt(curl_download, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl_download, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl_download, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, FALSE);
      //progress_bar : the fonction for the progress bar
      curl_easy_setopt(curl_download, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progress_bar);

      //Text color :   SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, nb_color);
      SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 11);
      cout<<" Start download"<<endl<<endl;

      res = curl_easy_perform(curl_download);

      fclose(fp);
      if(res == CURLE_OK)
      {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 10);
        cout<<endl<<endl<<" The file was download with succes"<<endl;
      }
      else
      {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 4);
        cout<<endl<<endl<<" Error"<<endl;
      }
      curl_easy_cleanup(curl_download);
  }
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 11);
  return 0;
}
```