# libcurl c CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION

Tags: c, libcurl

I need to know the status of my download using libcurl in C. I found that I have to use CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION.

```
int progress_func(void* ptr, double TotalToDownload, double NowDownloaded, 
                    double TotalToUpload, double NowUploaded)
{
   //Bla bla
}

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, FALSE);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progress_func);
```

I can't understand two things:
1) This function progress_func "how often" is called?
2) How can I pass other parameters to progress_func function? Because I have to write the connection status (speed, tot downloaded) in a file with a variable url, so I have to pass this url to the function.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614062/libcurl-console-progress-bar-for-file-download/10614757#10614757 for a detailed answer on progress bars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPROGRESSDATA):

```
struct my_progress_data_struct
{
    /* Some data fields */
};

struct my_progress_data_struct progress_data;

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, &progress_data);
```

The data will be passed in the `ptr` argument of the progress callback.

As for the first question, according to the [API reference](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPROGRESSFUNCTION) the callback will be called "roughly once per second or sooner".