# curl_multi_fdset returns always 1

Tags: c++, curl, curl-multi

**What I want to do:** download multiple files at the same time.

**Issue:** `curl_multi_fdset` always return 1.

**Issue 2:** I don't really understand how fd_set work. I am new to C and the doc is quite confusing.

**Sources**: I used [this example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/curl/curl/master/docs/examples/10-at-a-time.c) and [this progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637587/c-libcurl-console-progress-bar).

**My full .cpp**: [Github](https://github.com/Merkaber/ImageDownloader/blob/master/main.cpp)

So the problem seems to be in the initializing method:

```
static void initialize(CURLM *cm, int i, char* url[], std::string filepath)
{
CURL *eh = curl_easy_init();

FILE *fp; // added to the example
fp = fopen(filepath.c_str(), "wb"); // added to the example

curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);
curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp); // added to the example
curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0); // added to the example
curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_URL, url[i]);
curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, url[i]);
curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progress_func); // added to the example

curl_multi_add_handle(cm, eh);
}
```

However, it also won't work without these additional options. So it has to be something different but I didn't change anything regarding the fd_set. Any help is appreciated.

Call of initialize:

```
CURLM *cm = nullptr;
CURLMsg *msg;
long L;
unsigned int C = 0;
int M, Q, U = -1;
fd_set R, W, E;
struct timeval T;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
/* we can optionally limit the total amount of connections this multi handle uses */
curl_multi_setopt(cm, CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS, (long) MAX);

if ((argc - 2) < MAX)
{
    for (C = 0; C < argc - 2; ++C)
    {
        path = "test" + std::to_string(C) + ".html";
        initialize(cm, C, urls, path);
    }
}
```

Call of the function which returns 1:

```
FD_ZERO(&R);
FD_ZERO(&W);
FD_ZERO(&E);

if (curl_multi_fdset(cm, &R, &W, &E, &M))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "E: curl_multi_fdset\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: Is the variable `cm` is initialized? you call : `cm = curl_multi_init();` somewhere ?

Comment: 3 hours of search... just for that. Thanks a lot tunglt!! Although it won't save anything within my file it runs and compiles! Nice!