# Downloading File with libcurl in c++

Tags: c++, http, sockets, download

I am trying to download a zip file from a website but running into a few issues.

http://ampaste.net/m1632f19a

I implemented libcurl, followed some examples on downloading a file, used a big zip file so I could watch the progress %. It takes about 20 seconds to download, when it completes I go look and there is no file.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636333/download-file-using-libcurl-in-c-c)

[This post](http://www.unix.com/high-level-programming/37912-libcurl-progress-data.html) seems to use

```
double* Bar;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, &Bar);
```

maybe it is a progress specific problem. Have you tried without the progress stuff?