# Can one read a remote file as an istream with libcurl?

Tags: c++, libcurl, istream

I'd like to use the libcurl library to open a remote date file and iterate through it with an istream.  I've looked through the nice example in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636333/download-file-using-libcurl-in-c-c) but it writes the remote file to a local file.  Instead I'd like to have the remote reads be pushed to an istream for subsequent programmatic manipulation.  Is this possible?  I would greatly appreciate help.

Best,
Aaron

Comment: I don't know about libcurl, but how about ASIO?

Comment: @anybody +1 since ASIO has exactly that (streams), but it does not implement any protocols itself (HTTP, FTP, etc) which curl does.

Answer (score 2):

[Boost's IO Stream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) might be a better solution than STL's own stream.  At least it is much simpler to create a boost stream.  From boost's own docs:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

class CURLDevice
{
    private:
        CURL* handle;
    public:
        typedef char                            char_type;
        typedef boost::iostreams::source_tag    category;

        CURLDevice()
        {
            handle = curl_easy_init();
        }

        CURLDevice(const std::string &url)
        {
            handle = curl_easy_init();
            open( url );
        }

        ~CURLDevice()
        {
            curl_easy_cleanup(handle);
        }

        void open(const std::string &url)
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
            curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY, 1);
            curl_easy_perform(handle);
        }

        std::streamsize read(char* s, std::streamsize n)
        {
            size_t read;
            CURLcode ret = curl_easy_recv(handle, s, n, &read);
            if ( ret == CURLE_OK || ret == CURLE_AGAIN )
                return read;
            else
                return -1;
        }
};

typedef boost::iostreams::stream<CURLDevice> CURLStream;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    {
        CURLStream stream("http://google.com");

        char buffer[256];
        int sz;

        do
        {
            sz = 256;
            stream.read( buffer, sz );
            sz = stream.gcount();
            std::cout.write( buffer, sz );
        }
        while( sz > 0 );
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Note: when I run the code above I get a segfault in CURL, this appears to be because I don't know exactly how to use curl itself.

Comment: Thanks Gianni.  I am quite unfamiliar with boost iostreams.  Could you possibly elaborate the example to show how this would interact with a libcurl remote file access and subsequent use of the boost stream for programmatic reading?