# Getting text content below a specific line number

Tags: php

I'm working with PHP here.

I want to extract the text below a specific line number. The reason why I want I want to do this is to remove HTTP Header information from a CURL response.

Below is some code from sample response data:

```
HTTP/1.1 203 OK
Date: Tue, 23 Aug 2011 20:56:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4   Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=ke0uv5bm0mqjn3i3jad6n20co4; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Test-Header: This is my test header
Content-Length: 24
Content-Type: text/html

This is the get response
```

What I'd like to do is remove all the header information and return only my content i.e. "This is my get response".

I've done this successfully with regular expressions, but I want to do something that simple clears the content above the main response, rather than match header content then replace with empty space.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Set CURLOPT_HEADER to false , [cURL options](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html)

Comment: Are you using cURL from within PHP, or is the response in a separate file that you need to process using PHP?

Comment: @Ilya: Thanks, I know about the CURLOPT_HEADER setting to false. However, I need the HTTP Headers as well for my script, I just need to separate the headers from the main content.

Comment: @Richard: I'm using CURL from within PHP. I need the headers, I just want to separate the header information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove HTTP headers from CURL response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142869/how-to-remove-http-headers-from-curl-response)

Comment: @bazmegakapa: No, it's not a duplicate. I actually need the headers, I just want to separate the headers from the actual content. This is a string manipulation operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little poking around and here's what I came up with as a solution.

To get the number of line numbers taken up by my header content I wrote the following code:

```
$pattern_1_str = '/(http\/\d\.\d)\s+([\d]+)\s+([\w\-\/\'\"\(\)\\\. ]+)/i';
$pattern_2_str = '/([\w\-]+)\:\s+(.+)/i';

$matches_1_arr = array();
$matches_2_arr = array();

preg_match_all($pattern_1_str, $curl_response_res, $matches_1_arr);
preg_match_all($pattern_2_str, $curl_response_res, $matches_2_arr);

$line_count_1_str = count($matches_1_arr[0]);
$line_count_2_str = count($matches_2_arr[0]);

$line_num_offset_str = bcadd(1, bcadd($line_count_1_str, $line_count_2_str, 0), 0);
```

And then to get content only, the following code will do that:

```
$val_str_arr = array();
$val_str_arr = explode("\n", trim($curl_response_res));

$line_num_int = intval($line_num_offset_str);

$val_str_slice_arr = array();
$val_str_slice_arr = array_slice($val_str_arr, $line_num_int);

$curl_response_content_only_str = implode("\n", $val_str_slice_arr);
```

Where `$curl_response_res` is the response data as mentioned in my question above.

I'm not sure how efficient this code is, but for simple and relatively short response data from CURL it looks like it'll do ok.

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want the headers? Tell cURL not to give you headers:

```
$ch1 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php - this suggests that you should pass a boolean value as the third parameter when using 'CURLOPT_HEADER'

Comment: @NullUserException: I'm familiar with this, but I need the headers, I just want to have them removed after I'm done with them.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `file()`. For example, you could do this:

```
$URL = 'www.whatever.com';

$URL = file($URL);

$count = count($URL);

$line_number = 15; // for example

for($I=$line_number; $I<=$count; $I++){
  echo $URL[$I];
}
```

Hope that works.

Comment: `file()` doesn't return headers, so this is is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need the headers, you can get the headers separately from the cURL

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
print_r(get_headers($url)); //returns headers array
```

and execute your cURL with

```
$ch1 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

as mentioned

(probably not very fast though and may not work for re-directs)