# Setting CURL headers using CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER creates CORS problem

Tags: php, http, curl, cors

I am trying to do a cURL POST request defining HTTP Headers with PHP and I am getting CORS problem.

So I have a .php file that is called from a webapp using AJAX. In this .php file I am doing a HTTP POST request to an external API using cURL. It all worked fine until I had to set different HTTP Headers for authentication purposes. When I try to define the HTTP Headers in the cURL request using:

```
//Set Headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Authorization': 'someAuthorization',
  'x-api-key': 'somekey',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));
```

I start getting a CORS problem between the client (webapp) and my own endpoint which wasnt happening before. I tried to define the headers again after executing the cURL request but it didnt work:

```
//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if($result === false){
  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}else{
//$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
//CORS
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    //header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');    
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS"); 
}   
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 
{$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    exit(0);
}
echo $result;
};
```

Any ideas why this is happening? To me it seems that by performing the cURL request I am overriding the headers with cURL so the CORS header configuration is never applied.

Heres all the code in the .php file

```
<?php

$url = 'someurl';
$fields = ['pax' => '2', 'ownerid' => '1', 'channel' => '3'];

//url-ify the data for the POST
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//So that curl_exec returns the contents of the cURL; rather than echoing it
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

//Set Headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Authorization': 'someAuth',
'x-api-key': 'someKey',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
));

//DISABLE SSL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if($result === false){
  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}else{
  //$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  //CORS
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    //header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');    
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS"); 
  }   
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:{$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    exit(0);
  }
  echo $result;
};

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting some headers in the curl request dont changes header in your .php script.

**UPDATE 1:**

There is a parse error in your php script (As you found out by yourself):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Authorization': 'someAuthorization',
  'x-api-key': 'somekey',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));
```

Should be:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Authorization: someAuthorization',
  'x-api-key: somekey',
  'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));
```

The ajax call to this script result in an error 500 response which has default headers and **NOT** the headers you try to set in your .php script.

Enable error reporting in your local environment to see the problem "earlier".

for example in php.ini:

```
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED 
display_errors=On
```

@see [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: I already tried that and it didn´t work. Actually thats how it was in the first place, I just moved it down because I thought cURL was the issue. But still get CORS error: 

    "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
    'http://localhost/booking/makeTempBooking.php' from origin 
    'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control- 
    Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: Just for testing, you can try set * to allow all. header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
You could also check in browser debug console (network) what headers are coming back from you request. (Chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome)

Comment: Yes, I did that already and its really weird because theres no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin-*' headers in the Response Headers:

`Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 416
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 24 Dec 2018 18:38:09 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.4`

Comment: Maybe it gets removed by apache? .htaccess or apache httpd.conf / extras/*.conf?

Comment: Hmmmm, maybe the return from curl has also headers included (header+body). $result = curl_exec($ch); you use echo $result later. I think there are options to remove headers from response curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

@see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142869/how-to-remove-http-headers-from-curl-response

Comment: I finally found out what is going on. As I suppoused the error when setting the 'CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER'. I had:

//Set Headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Authorization': 'someAuth',
'x-api-key': 'someKey',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
));
And just realized it should be:

//Set Headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Authorization : someAuth',
'x-api-key : someKey',
'Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 ));

Comment: Ah ok, i missed that also :D

Comment: no comments... haha thank you anyway for the support!

Comment: But one question :o Does your old code with wrong quotes not throw a php fatal error? Its not a valid php syntax: array('Somevalue': 'somevalue'); ?
It should output something like Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in

Comment: Yea It is very weird but it doesn´t :/

Comment: Maybe you have not enabled error_reporting and display_errors in your configuration? If you work on local environment i prefer enable this in php.ini.

// 
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
//
display_errors=On

Comment: @totalx i have updated my answer. Maybe its usefull for other people run into CORS problem.