# Get text from site

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Saving a webpage to disk using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937283/saving-a-webpage-to-disk-using-c)

I am trying to grab text from an authorization php script I made. What the script does is check GET vars for a username and password and depending if the user/pass combo is correct returns a string and if not correct another string.

My question is, how do I in c++ query the website with the get url's, then fetch the string.

Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385483(VS.85).aspx

Comment: The usual answer for almost any question about "how do I fiddle with URLs in (C|C++)" is [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an client side library like **[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)** for the http.

Comment: or [curl++](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/cplusplus/)