# Reading contents of a webpage programatically

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008

I am attempting to download the contents of some specific web pages using C++ in Visual Studio 2008. I found a previous SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389069/programmatically-reading-a-web-page). That question had two answers but I can't make either of them work.

With regard the "libcurl" answer, I have failed to find the correct download for visual studio. I found some [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/visual_studio.pdf) which suggested that the download should contain “curllib.dsw", but I failed to find a download that included this file.

With regard the "windows code" answer... I tried it and it works perfectly for downloading the homepage of any website, eg, "www.sample.com", but I failed work out how to modify the code to download the contents of arbitrary URLs, e.g. "www.sample.com/subdir/subpage.htm".

Comment: try this with WinInet http://stackoverflow.com/a/29552504/4603670

Comment: Perfect. Tested and working. Thank you.

Comment: For the Windows answer, I think it's just replacing `GET /` with `GET /subdir/subpage.htm` for your example. Figured this out (or rather confirmed this) by following the comments in the linked thread.