# Hide CHtmlView Download Dialog Box

Tags: c++, mfc, mdi

I have created a basic `CHtmlView` in an MDI application, that I can use to navigate to Winrar downloading link for example (https://www.win-rar.com/predownload.html?&L=0&Version=32bit).

Once I click on download, the following two dialog box pop out :

[image: Example]

What I want to achieve is making the download happen in the background without those two dialog box showing up, Is such thing is possible? and how to achieve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you want to show the user the web page or just do the download? I haven't used ChtmlView in over a decade, but. There is also `SetSilent()`, might work. But, if you just want to do a download there is boost::asio or boost::beast. I've used both for downloads.

Comment: You can use APIs to download directly, [see example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29552504/4603670)

Comment: Hi @Barmak Shemirani Thanks for that heads up. So unlike Microsoft to make it look not painful. And an understood cert for https!!

Comment: @lakeweb, yes I want to show a web page more precisely this web view

[Example](https://i.imgur.com/jBjokS1.png)

In which a Kendo UI Spread Sheet is implemented, this web page offers the user the possibility to download the Spread Sheet by Clicking the icon in the red rectangle.

Comment: @lakeweb And using `SetSilent()`does not prevent the the download dialog box from showing up

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, if I can find away to intercept the message sent when the user click on the download button, I will be able to realize the download in a custom way.

Comment: You can override `OnBeforeNavigate2`