# Setup type program, how can i download something from the web in a c++ program?

Tags: c++, download

I'm making a program to setup a server, but I can't find out how to download a file from the internet in the c++ program. Preferably downloading a library or something.
Also, I am still a beginning programmer.
I'm using:
Microsoft Windows 7 Professional 64x
Notepad ++
Borland's C++ compiler v5.1

Comment: Why are you using a 10+ year old compiler?

Comment: Borland 5.1? What is this... 1999?

Comment: Check out [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Comment: So you're using a very old compiler with a very poor text editor to try to do something very advanced - setting up a server and downloading files in a system-level programming language. My recommendation: start with a high level language (like Ruby or Python) and _then_ move on to lower-level languages, like C++

Comment: @NikBougalis wow lol, maybe his mentor is making him use outdated technology so he appreciates modern conveniences

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient compiler? Get Visual Studio. Microsoft even provides [a free version](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop) if you have budgeting issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of doing that. The best for you way to go about this, in my opinion, is by using [cURL library](http://curl.haxx.se) (aka `libcurl`). Start from reading some [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/). [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1636415/405725) can also be helpful as it does exactly that. And of course you can always go other (less popular?) ways:

1. Use Qt Network library ([example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/Qt/DownloadfromURL.htm)).
2. Use Poco C++ Libraries (here is some [introductory PDF](http://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf)).
3. Find some other libraries and try them out.
4. Do it yourself.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, based on the choice of compiler, I see you want the hard way. [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will work. If you feel very adventurous, try [windows sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).