# Get XML from a web page

Tags: c++, xml

Can you tell me how can I make a program that automatically downloads an XML of an URL and takes it's titles, ddescription etc.. If you can recommend me a good API or library, please give me and a link to tutorials how to use it. :)

Comment: What platform ? on Windows you can use the function URLDownloadToFile.

Comment: Yes, it's Windows XP.. how can I use this function?

Comment: "titles, ddescription": are you sure you don't mean 'XHTML'? "An XML of an URL" would mean *any* XML file, and neither 'title' nor 'description' are standard XML elements. Also: whatever the answer, you cannot *choose* to download something "as" XML. You can only get what has been offered for download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the cross platform [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) to easily download webpages through http (and various other protocols).

Check out this answer for a simple example [Download file using libcurl in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636333/download-file-using-libcurl-in-c-c)