# C program for downloading files with curl

Tags: c, linux, unix, curl

I am trying to write a program in **C** to download some files.

### The source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written;
    written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

int main(){

    if(curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL)){
        printf("curl error. Exiting.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char links[3][100] = {
        "http://download.freeroms.com/nes_roms/08/big_nose_the_caveman.zip",
        "http://download.freeroms.com/nes_roms/02/contra.zip",
        "http://download.freeroms.com/nes_roms/08/super_mario_bros._(usajapan).zip"};
    int n = 0, k = 0;
    char *lastslash;
    char* name;

    CURL *handle = curl_easy_init();
    CURLcode res;
    FILE *file;

    while(n<3){
        lastslash = strrchr(links[n], '/');
        name = lastslash ? lastslash + 1 : links[n];
        printf("\nURL: %s\n", links[n]);
        printf("Filename: %s\n", name);

        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, links[n]);
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, file);
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

        file = fopen(name, "wb");       
        res = curl_easy_perform(handle);

        fclose(file);
        n++;
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

I can compile it, but this is the output when I run it :

> URL: http://download.freeroms.com/nes_roms/08/big_nose_the_caveman.zip
> Filename: big_nose_the_caveman.zip
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

My compiler setting:

> gcc dl.c -lcurl -o dl

I found out that the problem occurs when it tries to execute `curl_easy_perform()`, but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: What is curl_easy_init() returning?

Comment: Have a look at [this][1] page, it is already discussed.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636333/download-file-using-libcurl-in-c-c

Comment: you should check if the return of curl_easy_init() is != NULL

Comment: @dckuehn It doesn't return anything, when the program gets to that code, it closes and writes Segmentation fault to the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the file before you set the callback data. The `FILE*` is stored by value, not reference.

```
    file = fopen(name, "wb");       
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, file);
```

Answer (score 4):

try this coding.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/types.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <string>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

int main(void) {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = "http://localhost/aaa.txt";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "C:\\bbb.txt";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/aaa.txt");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```