# Getting the url of m3u8 asset when loaded by a webpage

Tags: c++, web-scraping, html, libcurl

I am writing a program that has the user enter the url of a webpage with a video on it. The program will take that and pull down the website. The program will then pull the m3u8 link from the website and return it.

From what I have researched it seems the best way to get the webpage is using curl. My question is, once I have the webpage, how do I find that particular asset?

Answer (score 0):

A [similar question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636333/download-file-using-libcurl-in-c-c). The user who posted the question asked how to download the video and close it. The working code was posted, but subsequently deleted.

This was the working code [using libcurl/c++  etc]:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/types.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <string>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written;
    written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

int main(void) {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = "http://localhost/aaa.txt";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "C:\\bbb.txt";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also the [libcurl site](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) has other sample code on it that you may find useful.

Hope this helps

Comment: p.s. m3u8 are not strictly speaking "video" files - the content is text-based... sorry for being pedantic