# Downloading a file using libcurl in C using SFTP: "Unsupported protocol" in c, but command line works

Tags: c, curl, download, sftp, libcurl

I based my code on [Download file using libcurl in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636333/download-file-using-libcurl-in-c-c) but I'm getting an ERROR: **"Unsupported protocol"** for **SFTP**. However, for the same **SFTP**, file download and upload works with the command line.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    //char *url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    char *url = "sftp://dheerajr@10.4.1.156/home/dheerajr/temp/download.txt";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "temp.txt";
    curl = curl_easy_init();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    if (curl)
    {   
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res == CURLE_OK)
            printf("Download Successfull\n");
        else
            printf("ERROR: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

checked with curl -V command which supports **SFTP**. **curl -V** output:

```
curl 7.72.0-DEV (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.72.0-DEV OpenSSL/1.1.1 zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) libssh2/1.8.2 nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: [unreleased]
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: did you had any luck with finding a solution? I have the same issue!

Comment: yes, I found the solution need compile with by enabling the different option

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile ssh2 library first and that reconfigure curl library with --with-libssh2="path" and recompile. then  you will have the ssh function call working with curl api's.

Good Luck ;-)