# build libcurl on windows with sftp support

Tags: windows, curl, sftp, libcurl

My application needs a curl sftp. I ran sample which got error message **"Protocol "sftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl"**.
After doing some research, I came to know that we need to build libcurl from source code by enabling the "libssh2". That's what I am trying to do.

reading docs/readme etc. I did below steps:

1. I got the source code from git.
2. On VS developer command tool, created curl-build folder. Ran cmake.
   Got the message **"Build files have been written to: c:/curl-build"**.
3. Now, I don't know how to proceed further. The docs don't have any info. how to enable sftp support.

Could anyone help me with any info. on how to build libcurl on windows enabling sftp?
or if I there is any version of libcurl already available with sftp?

Update:

I followed the link mentioned in the comments below. I got a follow-up question on that since I am working on windows.

I used WSL to configure on windows.
I got below error.
configure: error: one or more libs available at link-time are not available run-time. Libs used at link-time: -lssh2 -lz

I followed https://curl.se/mail/lib-2012-08/0121.html but my issue didn't get resolved.

Comment: The readme guides you through specific configuration steps. You should not expect that it guides beginners from 0 to ready to run app, or teach how to use build tools. For further progress you might follow CMake tutorials.

Comment: I am not asking to help to build library. I need command to enable SFTP on windows for libcurl. I looked at docs. The information is not found. Then only I posted question here.

Comment: The dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63356150/downloading-a-file-using-libcurl-in-c-using-sftp-unsupported-protocol-in-c-b