# libcurl simple C file downloader example immediately returns

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

I tried compiling both the examples on this question: [Download file using libcurl in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636333/download-file-using-libcurl-in-c-c)

Here's one of them:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "page.html";
    curl = curl_easy_init();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    if (curl)
    {   
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

the problem is that this example, when run, immediately returns and I get a blank file. Why? I modified to

```
if (curl)
{   
    fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(fp);
} else {
    printf("error\n");
}
```

but I see no error. I tried compiling in both C++ and C, I get the same result on both.

Comment: Check what the `res` value after `curl_easy_perform`, and refer to the documentation (https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) to try and understand the error.

Comment: You should check and test `res`, but your code does not

Comment: Try printing out `curl_easy_strerror(res)`.

Comment: @Galik it prints `No error`

Comment: `curl_easy_perform` is returning `0`

Comment: wireshark inspection shows that the page returns a `302` moved permanently. Calling a website that does return `200` works.

Comment: Maybe you should consider asking libcurl to follow redirects? (That's what a 302 is...)

Comment: Hint two: add CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L and you would've diagnosed that 302 thing in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

According to https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html, `true` tells the library to follow HTTP location.